# One motherboard crashed. Changed and wants to crash again

Tags: motherboard, freeze, repair

My computer started to freeze randomly. I was pretty sure it was the hard drive that was starting to fail. Before I could change it, the motherboard was completely dead. I bought the same one and reinstall it. Everything went working well until my computer started to freeze again and doing the same problem has before. I don't want my motherboard to burn again and I'm really wondering what can be the problem...

Could it be the power supply or the video cards that burned the motherboard ? I tested the voltages of the power supply and they seemed fine...
The computer worked as is for four years...

Here are the specs:

ASUS P5N-D Motherboard LGA 775 NVIDIA 750i SLI
Intel Q6600
2X EN9600GT 512mb
650w Corsair

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the motherboard had a design flaw?  Did you get new memory with that board, or did you swap the old?

A possible scenario here is that some condition external to the motherboard is *triggering* a hardware bug.  This could indeed be the power supply under load, or a change in the usage pattern of your system.  (New software exercising the graphics card in different ways).

Hardware is notoriously hard to debug, if you don't have access to the right tools (and know how to use them).

Comment: Yes, I first swapped the memory. I'll test under ubuntu with heavy load to stress test the material. If I find nothing special, maybe this will mean that I'll look into the hard drive and the os... Either ways, this problem is really strange and I'll keep this updated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Years ago I had similar problems with an AMD CPU/VIA KT(133?) chipset combination. In the middle of any activity, the screen would just freeze. The Via Arena forums had many similar reports, and it was suggested that the power supply was just under par, which could cause the agp graphics card to lock up.